# Why does `su` not work in Jenkins?

Tags: shell, jenkins, su

`su` doesn't seem to work as intended when run in Jenkins build job script.

```
su username1234
whoami
```

returns `jenkins`

My initial guess is that each line of the Jenkins shell script is a new shell. But doing repeated `echo $$` on separate lines shows that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su` doesn't enter an interactive session when in a non-interactive session the way it does in an interactive session.

In a shell script you get to run a single command in the `su` context `su <user> <command>`.